# Fallout 4 - How do I change modes when manipulating objects?

Tags: pc, fallout-4, keyboard

I am one of those guys that has built my settlers a mansion with a fully-stocked kitchen, games room, and hospital bay.

The problem is, stacking shelves and aligning objects is *huge* pain. Sometimes I'll pick something up (holding E) and I'll be able to rotate it (using LMB/RMB) on it's Y axis, sometimes on it's X, and sometimes a mixture of the two. It seems to depends on what starting orientation the object has when picked up as to which axis it rotates on.

I would like to know if there is any way (button or otherwise) to switch rotation axis modes whilst manipulating an object. I have looked in the controls and all the settings and can't see anything that affects this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer by pressing every single keybound button listed in the controls until I got an axis switch. The key to do this is SHIFT (standard controls, whichever key is used for sprint otherwise).